# MATLAB+Arduino+LCD

Tags: lcd, matlab

[image]

I am trying to send some integers to an LCD. But it is not working. I have tried in Proteus. Please help. I have uploaded MATLAB and Arduino code below.

MATLAB code:

```
clear all
clc

 answer=1; % this is where we'll store the user's answer
 arduino=serial('COM1','BaudRate',9600); % create serial communication object on port COM4

fopen(arduino); % initiate arduino communication

while answer
fprintf(arduino,'%s',char(answer)); % send answer variable content to arduino
answer=input('Enter led value 1 or 2 (1=ON, 2=OFF, 0=EXIT PROGRAM): '); % ask user to enter value for variable answer
end

fclose(arduino); % end communication with arduino
```

Arduino code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
int matlabData;
LiquidCrystal lcd(12,11,5,4,3,2);

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()>0) {
    matlabData=Serial.read();
    lcd.print(matlabData);
  }
}
```

Comment: *What* exactly is not working? The LCD?  Setting up the COM port on the host? Receiving serial data on the arduino? What have you tried?

Comment: lcd shows nothing.I have given the input with the help of MATLAB but still lcd shows nothing.

Comment: Not a Matlab expert, but if you enter '1', doesn't `input' yield the *int* 1? If sou, you are trying to display not the character '1', but the byte *1*.

Comment: First, try to write anything to the LCD. Not serial data, just 'hello world'. See if that works.

Comment: With the help of ARDUINO,it works.But if I use matlab,it doesn't work.I am gonna upload a pic,take a look....

Comment: With the help of ARDUINO,I have tried.It worked.The problem arises when i use MATLAB.

Comment: *Sigh* getting serial ports to work with Matlab is a nightmare. Are you sure that part is working correctly? Try hooking it up to a PC and use an app like RealTerm or TerraTerm to make sure that piece is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Matlab's Arduino support package, it allows you to control the Arduino directly without having to write code in the Arduino IDE. I never used it with an LCD though. Here is [a link](https://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/arduino-matlab.html) that might help.

Comment: I already have installed all the packages required for arduino.This is working for led only.With the help of matlab I can easily control a led.But in case of lcd,I am facing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
while answer
  fprintf(arduino,'%s',char(answer)); % send answer variable content to arduino
  answer=input('Enter led value 1 or 2 (1=ON, 2=OFF, 0=EXIT PROGRAM): ');
  % ask user to enter value for variable answer
end
```

Is it just me or should asking the user to input something be ***before*** printing it?

Also, more importantly, isn't `fprintf(arduino, '%s', char(answer));` printing raw bytes? In which case, you would be sending 0x01/0x02. Not a great idea... In your Arduino code, print out on Serial what you are receiving, in [hexa]decimal, not as `char`.

```
    matlabData=Serial.read();
    Serial.print("Received: [0x");
    if(matlabData<16)Serial.write('0');
    Serial.print(matlabData, HEX);
    Serial.println("]");
```

This should give you a better idea whether you received anything, and if so, what.